# Audio glitches VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the first 3 seconds of the audio sample here:
https://we.tl/pDHw6ob2JA

You will hear 2 audio glitches. They occur when you have audio cuts in the sequencer, in this sample you have 3 strips next to each other. First clip length is 5 frame, second is 18 frames long.
This isn't the first time I notice this problem and it isn't related to a specific version of blender. I've managed in the past to get ride of these by adding keyframes in the graph editor, reducing the volume to zero at the end of the strip and on the next strip fading the audio in in a similar way. It's a very time consuming process when you have hundreds of cuts and it doesn't work all the time. Do you have any other suggestions? Those of you who have experience with other editing software, is this a problem you've noticed elsewhere or is it specific to Blender?

Comment: I do most of my Audio editing in [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) and only import the final result to be rendered out via Blender.

Comment: Here is a new link: https://we.tl/pDHw6ob2JA